# Is there a way in cmake to save away the install_manifest.txt for later

Tags: cmake

What is the best way to save away the install_manifest.txt file at install time so it can be used later for an uninstall.

This is a naive attempt that doesn't work because the file doesn't exist at this point.

```
install(FILES "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install_manifest.txt" DESTINATION /etc/${PROJECT_NAME})
```

---

**-- EDIT --**

I'm going with the solution from @havogt.  I thought I would add the final result since I also tacked the manifest file itself onto the end.  I'm also leaving my destination variable in there to make @KamilCuk a bit happier.

It's worth noting this must appear last or there will be missing files.

```
set(INSTALL_SHAREDIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/share/${PROJECT_NAME})
install(CODE "string(REPLACE \";\" \"\\n\" MY_CMAKE_INSTALL_MANIFEST_CONTENT \"\$\{CMAKE_INSTALL_MANIFEST_FILES\}\")\n\
            file(WRITE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/MANIFEST.txt \"\$\{MY_CMAKE_INSTALL_MANIFEST_CONTENT\}\\n${INSTALL_SHAREDIR}/MANIFEST.txt\")")
install(FILES "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/MANIFEST.txt" DESTINATION ${INSTALL_SHAREDIR})
```

Comment: `DESTINATION /etc/` Ugh, `etc` is for configuration. For package specific stuff use `/usr/share/the_package/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a documented way to achieve that. It seems writing of the `install_manifest.txt` is the very last thing that happens during installation.

However, if you really want to do it and want to rely on implementation detail of CMake, you can achieve what you want as follows.

The code that is used to write the `install_manifest.txt` comes from [cmLocalGenerator.cxx](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/0020f69848e6a80858e9b56fc351d7644cff6e4d/Source/cmLocalGenerator.cxx#L720). You can use the same pattern to write the content to your desired location. The information is contained in the CMake variable `CMAKE_INSTALL_MANIFEST_FILES`.

Adding the following to your CMake project will write the content of `install_manifest.txt` to a file called `my_install_manifest.txt`.

```
install(CODE "string(REPLACE \";\" \"\\n\" MY_CMAKE_INSTALL_MANIFEST_CONTENT \"\$\{CMAKE_INSTALL_MANIFEST_FILES\}\")\n\
              file(WRITE my_install_manifest.txt \"\$\{MY_CMAKE_INSTALL_MANIFEST_CONTENT\}\")")
```

Check `cmake_install.cmake` in your build directory to see what will be executed during installation.

Obviously, there is no guarantee that this will work in future versions of CMake.

Comment: Nice work!  For me it produces the exact same output.  I'd say this is as good as it gets for now.